# Vuetify - wrap header text on v-data-table

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying hard to get the header text wrapped on a v-data-table component. I tried applying a style to the component - any style that I apply to the tbody elements within the table are being applied. However, I could not get any custom style working for the header (thead element). Please help.

For example, if I have a header such this, how do I wrap it?

{ text: `Calories - Very Long Column Name Here which needs to be wrapped to the next line`, value: 'calories' , align: 'center',}

Please see this [code pen link](https://codepen.io/vilaspd/pen/GxXBVG)

Thanks,
Vilas

Comment: You can add `class` property on your header object (inside headers array), class is then applied to header. [Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api) says you can also add `width`, but seems like it's not working?

Answer (score 5):

You can control width in the `headers` props. It is an array of objects that each describe a header column. See the example below for a definition of all properties.

```
{
  text: string
  value: string
  align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'
  sortable: boolean
  class: string[] | string
  width: string
}
```

But there is a bug, which will hopefully be fixed in the next version, so it doesn't work under all circumstances, especially not if you are using it inside a `v-flex`.

Also percantage (`width: '100%'`) works better than e.g. `width: '300px'`, at least for me.